# Can aws route53 point to my personal server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

some time ago I bought a domain name **mydomain.com** via the route53 service.
Till now I registered my record sets to point to my EC2 instances.

Now, I have another machine that is an actual phisical server reachable via its own public IP/hostname.
Would it be possible to create a record set in route53 to make my website accessible via the domain I bought? Like **external.service.mydomain.com** ? Or am I now chained to aws?

Comment: Have you actually tried? Or read any docs or done a quick web search? It's just DNS. You can put any IP you want in a Route53 record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not chained to aws, simply change (or add) your 'a' record to point to whatever ip address you want, and as long as that ip address is publicly reachable, it will work fine.